# Program will not recognize method I have created

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm a beginner, so my code is fairly rough. I made a object class of Squares. In my main program, I created an array of Squares, each with a square of different lengths. I can make the array and print out each element too.

I'm trying to make a method that combines all the areas of the squares in an array, then returns a rounded side length that results in square the the total area.

The part code of the method:

```
  public int totalArea(Square[] s)
   {
     int arraylength=s.length;
     int area_total=0;
     int area_ind=0; 
     double side_new=0;
     int side_real=0;

     for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
        {
          area_ind=s[i].area();
          area_total+=area_ind;
        }

    side_new= Math.sqrt(area_total);
    side_real= (int)(side_new);
    return side_real;

  }
```

This is the code of the actual 'main' file:

```
        public class as5_apprun
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           Square[] original=
          {  
             new Square(),
             new Square(1,new Point (0,0)),
             new Square(2,new Point (0,0)),
             new Square(3,new Point (0,0)),
             new Square(4,new Point (0,0)),
             new Square(5,new Point (0,0))
          };
```

This is the error:

```
     int total= totalArea(original);
     This fails giving the error
      int total= totalArea(original);
                 ^
         symbol:   method totalArea(Square[])
     location: class as5_apprun
       1 error
```

***Update:*** Problem was resolved in comments

Comment: Where is the `totalArea` method defined?

Comment: Are you importing the class with the totalArea method?

Comment: You know we can still see your code in the edit history, right?

Comment: Yes! I wanted to see how the edits would appear (sounds stupid, but I wanted to know!)

Comment: Your formatting is screwed up now. Please fix it. Welcome to SO `=)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `totalArea` as an instance method of `Square`, yet it only operates on an array of squares.

You should declare it `public static int totalArea(Square[] s)` and reference it as `int total= Square.totalArea(original);`

assuming that totalArea is inside `Square.java`.

Comment: Can you explain the difference that Static makes? Thanks again, I can't believe I forgot the Square. in front!

Comment: @user3538214 Static has to do with instantiation. If an object or method is Static it **cannot** be instantiated. Meaning only one of it can ever exist and it is shared by all the instances of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `totalArea` method is an instance method, you need to have an instance of `Square` class to invoke that method.

Other wise, declare the `totalArea` method as static, so that you can call that method without any instance of `Square`

```
total= Square.totalArea(original);
```

> Can you explain the difference that Static makes? Thanks again.

Static method are belongs to Classes, not to any instances, So, You can call those method without any instances.